# Facing 404 error after upgraded to Tomcat 7.0.54

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat7, http-status-code-404

Recently I have upgraded the tomcat version from 7.0.26 to 7.0.54, and now I am facing 404 error with tomcat 7.0.54 version.

I have tested with most of the version, till tomcat 7.0.53 my product help link works fine. I am not sure what change had made in 7.0.54 version.

Actual Issue:
                We have simple main_help.war file which is integrated in my product and on click on help link it launches new tab and shows html page runs on java.

This is the actual URL -   https://hostname.com:8444/main_help/help_services/html/admin_en_usa/index.htm?URL=admin_1_0_0/help_wrapper_topic.html&SHOWTOC=1&CHROME=false

with no change in our product and just updated tomcat to 7.0.54 version, the URL is not coming properly. main_help (which is the main war deployed in server (main_help.war)) string is missing in the URL.

This is the URL after upgraded to tomcat 7.0.54  - https://hostname.com:8444//help_services/html/admin_en_usa/index.htm?URL=admin_1_0_0/help_wrapper_topic.html&SHOWTOC=1&CHROME=false

OS Detail:
-          Windows 7 64bit.
-          Java 7
-          All browser type (same issue)

Could someone please help me what is the change that Apache made? And how can I modify my application accordingly.

Regards
Thiru

Comment: Are you url-encoding the value of that 'URL' parameter? I wouldn't expect a slash to be a proper character for an url parameter. Possibly until now you had a bug in your application and you were simply lucky that it happened to work - until the more recent slew of bugfixes done in Tomcat.

Comment: Thanks Gim, i am not encoding the URL parameter. the wired part is if i append main_help string in the URL and directly hit that, i can see the help page. my problem is main_help string is missing from the URL.

https://hostname.com:8444/main_help/help_services/html/admin_en_usa/index.htm?URL=admin_1_0_0/help_wrapper_topic.html&SHOWTOC=1&CHROME=false

can you see the differents here. 

https://hostname.com:8444/{missing_here}/help_services/html/admin_en_usa/index.htm?URL=admin_1_0_0/help_wrapper_topic.html&SHOWTOC=1&CHROME=false

Comment: What is weird? You get a wrong url, so it doesn't work. Of course it starts to work when you manually fix the url to be correct. Instead of blaming the tools, examine the logic which generates that url. How is it generated?

Comment: Nothing was added without testing which was working fine and with no change in our code and only changing tomcat  latest version, started giving error... anyway thanks for your input.
I am not blaming the tool and what i am asking here is, is there any new change in configuration which tomcat introduced so that i can incorporate in my product. i am looking into the tomcat 7.0.54 changelogs but i am not able to figure it out.